# htaccess remove get variable to make better url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a nice looking url that can change https://www.url.com/profile.php/?lang=en&user=1#userinfo into https://url.com/profile/en/1#userinfo.
And the lang variable is on every page.

I tried to get my extension away and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But now i need the get variables, i have looked around but nothing works.

Comment: "get the get variables" - is too elusive of a problem description.

Comment: ow my bad @mario

Comment: I don't see any parts there putting parts from the requested URL to GET parameters...

Comment: what do u mean @NicoHaase

Comment: You want to put stuff from the requested URL to GET parameters - that's what you have to write specific rules for, such that each part can be mapped to the proper parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php/16389034#16389034 will give you a hint about what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules check the request line `(e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1")`, the request path is `/profile.php`, and if contains the query string `lang=&user=`, redirect the request uri from `/profile.php` to `/profile/%1/%2`, `%1`, `%2` is the back-reference to match the grouped part `([^&]+)`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /profile\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)&user=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?profile.php$ /profile/%1/%2 [NE,R,L,QSA]
```

This rule internal rewrite the URL from `/profile/{lang}/{user_id}` to `/profile.php?lang={lang}&user_id={user_id}`. So when uri `/profile/en/1` is requested, the server knows the rewritten uri is `/profile.php?lang=en&user_id=1`.

```
RewriteRule ^/?profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?lang=$1&user_id=$2 [L]
```